# Accessing and using a search bar to enter data with python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, search, input

I hope you are having a great day.

Today I am trying to figure out how to get python to use a search bar. for work, my project requires me to go to a website that's simply a database with a search bar and you search for what you need.

End game would be to take numbers from an excel sheet and enter it into the search bar. I have been gaining familiarity with urllib but there doesnt seem to be an area of it to access a search bar but instead you set what you want to search before hand which defeats the purpose of automating this task.

any advice on resources or how to get started?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the website is structured, there might be a pretty easy way to do this.

If the Website uses GET Parameter you can send the Parameter via the URL. So you can use the standard Web API and just call the right URL:

```
url = # put url here
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
text = page.read()
page.close()
```

EDIT:
As found here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

POST is also pretty simple:

```
import urllib
params = urllib.urlencode({'spam': 1, 'eggs': 2, 'bacon': 0})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://www.musi-cal.com/cgi-bin/query", params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is urllib a requirement for your project? If not, I would suggest using [python-requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls)

From your description, it sounds like the search is a simple GET request with some sort of parameters. Here's an example of making such a request with python-requests:

```
payload = {'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
r = requests.get("http://httpbin.org/get", params=payload)
```

In the 'payload' dictionary you should have the parameter key(s) and value(s) for the search. I suggest you check out the documentation of python-requests for more info, it's very straight-forward and simple to understand.